# getting redactor video.js plugin installed

Tags: plugins, redactor, video

I tried to install the redactor video.js plugin but I can't make it work. I tried to intgrate it via "control panel js" plugin. Put the "video" tag under "buttons", but it doesn't appear. How do I integrate the video.js plugin properly?

Craft 3.5.13.2, Redactor 2.8.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the video button is supplied by a plugin, it should go under the `plugins` key rather than the `buttons` key. Your config would end up something like:

```json
{
  "buttons": ["html", "format", "bold", "italic", "lists", "link", "file"],
  "plugins": ["video"]
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, that was the knot in my head. well, one of them ;-)